# How can I search for an a list of words in a table of words that associate to another table?

Tags: mysql

Below are 3 tables I have setup.  The 'words' and 'word_part_mapping' tables are generated automatically by indexing all of the words in the part's name from the parts table.

```
//'parts' table
+----------+--------------+
| part_num | part_name    |
+----------+--------------+
| 10111    | front bumper |
| 10112    | rear bumper  |
+----------+--------------+


//'words' table
+------+------------+
| id   | word       |
+------+------------+
| 1    | front      |
| 2    | bumper     |
| 3    | rear       |
+------+------------+



//'word_part_mapping' association table
+---------+----------+
| word_id | part_num |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 10111    |
| 2       | 10111    |
| 3       | 10112    |
| 1       | 10112    |
+---------+----------+
```

How can I query this if the user searches for "front bumper" and I want the query to return results containing ALL words that the user searched for?

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM words w 
LEFT JOIN word_part_mapping wpm ON w.id=wpm.word_id
LEFT JOIN parts p ON wpm.part_num=p.part_num
WHERE w.word='front' AND w.word='bumper'
```

Obviously, the above query does not work because the word cannot equal both 'front' and 'bumper'.  This works if I do OR, however I do not want that because it returns too many results (50,000+ parts in database).

==============================================

EDIT: Got it working finally...

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM words w 
LEFT JOIN word_part_mapping wpm ON w.id=wpm.word_id 
LEFT JOIN parts p ON wpm.part_num=p.part_num 
WHERE w.word IN('front','bumper') 
GROUP BY p.part_num 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.word) = 2
```

where 2 is the number of terms the user is searching

Comment: Consider to post an answer to your question so that others can benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working finally...

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM words w 
LEFT JOIN word_part_mapping wpm ON w.id=wpm.word_id 
LEFT JOIN parts p ON wpm.part_num=p.part_num 
WHERE w.word IN('front','bumper') 
GROUP BY p.part_num 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.word) = 2
```

where 2 is the number of terms the user is searching

Answer (score 0):

How about just looking in `part_name` like this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM parts
 WHERE part_name LIKE '%front%' 
   AND part_name LIKE '%bumper%'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c93df/4)**

Comment: peterm:  Your solution is what I had been using in the past, but I am trying to avoid searching in the part_name field with wild cards because it returns way too many false positives.  It is also very slow (4-5 second query times) on a database of 50,000+ items with 100+ words in each part name/description.