# For an n:m relation how can I search for all n that have at least the m defined in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

## Question

I have a database with items and tags and the items can have any number of tags. Now I want to search for all items that have all of a given set of tags. The set I search for is also saved in a table. Here is what the tables look like:

```
|   items  |    |   tags   |
| id | ... |    | id | ... |
+----+-----+    +----+-----+   
| 1  | ... |    | 1  | ... |
| 2  | ... |    | 2  | ... |
| 3  | ... |

|     itemTags   |    |  tagSearch |
| itemId | tagId |    | id | tagId |
+--------+-------+    +----+-------+  
|   1    |   1   |    | 1  |   1   |
|   2    |   1   |    | 2  |   1   |
|   2    |   2   |    | 2  |   2   |
```

Now I can do e.g.

```sql
select items.id, tags.id
from items
left join itemTags on (items.id=itemTags.itemId)
left join tags on (tags.id=itemTags.tagId)
```

This will give me a list of all items and their tags. Precisely:

```
itemId | tagId
-------+-------
  1    |   1
  2    |   1
  2    |   2
  3    |   null
```

However I now want to filter this result with the help of the tagSearch table.

## Example 1

```sql
select ... from ... where tagSearch.id=1
```

Should result in

```
itemId | tagId
-------+-------
  1    |   1
  2    |   1
  2    |   2
```

This is still the same table as above, but without item 3, because that one does not have tag 1 which is required by tagSearch with id 1. Note especially that the thrid row is still present. I still want the list of all tags for each item as long as the search is fulfilled.

## Example 2

```sql
select ... from ... where tagSearch.id=2
```

should result in:

```
itemId | tagId
-------+-------
  2    |   1
  2    |   2
```

because only item 2 has both tags searched for. Note however that if item 2 would additionally have a tag 3, then this tag should be listed in the table-

Items will typically have a maximum of 10 tags and tagSearches will typically include only 1-2 tags and rare cases exceeding this.

This is similar to, but not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16455704/327301)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```sql
select items.id, tags.id
from items
left join itemTags on (items.id=itemTags.itemId)
left join tags on (tags.id=itemTags.tagId)
where not exists(
   select 1 from tagSearch
   left join itemTags on (itemTags.tagId=tagSearch.tagId)
   where itemTags.tagId is null and tagSearch.searchId=?
)
```

The idea is that a left join will fill the rows it does not find a match for with null values. Thus if we left join the tagSearch to the itemTags it means that for each value from the tagSearch that was not found and is thus not present in the itemTags table will be null. If we get no null values from the join, then we found a match, otherwise not. Thus we filter for only the null values. If we get a result it is a match, otherwise it is not. To check whether we got a result we use the exists() function and that's it.